# Contoller in magento2?

Tags: php, magento2.2, di

How to override `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave` contoller?

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave" type="Xxx\Order\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Address" />
```

**Contoller**

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Order\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave;


class Address extends AddressSave
{
    public function execute()
    {        
        echo "hi";
        exit;}}
```

I am trying to do this but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Yyy\Plugin;

use  Xxx\Zzz\Model\Data;
class AddressSave
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    protected $_pincodeModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,Data $pincodeModel    )
    {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_pincodeModel = $pincodeModel;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave $subject, \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $codAvailability = $this->_pincodeModel->isDeliveryAvailable($postCode) ? "yes" : "no";
        if ($codAvailability == 'yes') {// Write your own logic here
            $result = $proceed();
            return $result;
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError('We can\'t update the order address right now.');
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

**di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave">
        <plugin name="admin_order_address_save" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\AddressSave" />
    </type>


}else {
        $action = $this->_request->getActionName();
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Delivery is not available at ' . $postCode));
        $this->_actionFlag->set($action, \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $redirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/addressSave', array('address_id' => $addressId));
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Is your module activated and installed properly ?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? I recommend you to use plugin instead of overriding the whole controller method. You can use before, after, or around plugin as per your need.

Comment: I want add additional condition for before address save...so i can use beforePlugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **around** plugin.

Create following files.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave">
        <plugin name="admin_order_address_save" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddressSave" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddressSave.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AddressSave
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $condition = 1; // Write your own logic here

        if ($condition == 1) {
            $result = $proceed();
            return $result;
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError('We can\'t update the order address right now.');
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you still face any problem, you can ask me.

Comment: no change ....after this @Dinesh

Comment: I have checked the code. It's working fine. It might be possible there is some mistake in your code. Please update your current code in the question.

Comment: Update my post..

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Xxx/Sales/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave" type="Xxx\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave" />
```

> app/code/Xxx/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddressSave.php

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class AddressSave extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    public function execute()
    {        
        echo "hi";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working